# Play sound in a Square Area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

How can I restrict sound in a **Square Area** not in a Circular area as Audio source provide min & max distance to do this job.

Is there any **built in option** (not with script, I have already done this but due to some limitation(trigger limitation) i don't want to use it) to restrict sound in a square area?